# Express Lagrange polynomial in term of Cauchy matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, cauchy-matrices

Given 2n distinct real numers $s_1,s_2, \dots, s_n$ and $t_1, t_2, \dots,t_n$ define the $n \times n$ Cauchy matrix $C = C(t,s)$ by $C_{ij} = \frac{1}{t_i - s_j}$. Express the Lagrange interpolation formula: 
$$p(t_i) = \sum_{j=1}^{n}L_j(t_i)f_j$$
where
$$L_j(t) = \prod_{k \neq j}\frac{t-s_k}{t_j - s_k}$$
in term of Cauchy matrix?

Can someone please explain to me how to express those term in Cauchy matrix ? Thank you

Comment: You can find your answer from  theorem 1 in [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1057113/references).